# icloud - removing previous connected apple devices and disconnecting it from account

Tags: icloud, apple-id, user-account

#### Context

Last year I got rid of two old Macs (one running macOS Catalina and the other with macOS Sierra, both were formatted in an attempt to reuse them for Linux).

In the process I removed them from my Apple ID via: Preferences - Apple ID - "Remove from Account" and they no longer had shown up within iCloud.

Anyway, today I was deleting an account from "internet accounts" and got a message warning me about the devices it will be removed from - including listing these two  Macs.

Curiously, I added these accounts a month ago - so how would it ever get linked with these  machines?

My question now is - how can I really really remove these Macs from my account?

In case it matters - they are with people I trust so I doubt I would be target of hacking.

#### Additional Information

- I have also confirmed on the iCloud website that these machines are removed.
- I have used the "deactivate all computers" function in iTunes last year when I got rid of the machines - it's now disabled saying "0 computers are activated".
- I have 2 factor activated - and didn't receive any unusual login requests.
- I got rid of a third (this time completely broken) newer Mac a few months back - but this one is not showing up (as it should).
- The deleted Account did not get removed on my iOS devices, they weren't mentioned in the warning either.

Comment: Have you looked on iCloud.com to see if they have gone?  You can force a logout from there (both for devices and Safari sessions).

Comment: Great question! Unfortunately, the answer will be: non-intuitive, awkward, subject to random & frequent change. OK - that's a negative view, but I run into similar things in macOS, and it often feels like trying to kill a snake.

Comment: @Seamus yeah I know.  It appears I encounter more and more of these oddities this year and when I got a little time at hand I try if I can get the Mac to "just work" again.

Comment: If you find something useful, please post it here as a answer to your own question! IIRC, you can select your own answer as the correct one - though you may have to wait a day or two after posting it.